# Android: opening activity from widget as dialog and disabling the background

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, widget

I am working on widget project and when I touch the widget a new activity that is styled like a dialog box. The main activity opens and the dialog styled activity appears and when I touch the main activity the dialog styled activity disappears. 
1) Is there a way to disable the activity? or 
2) Is there away to open the dialog styled activity without opening the activity?

Here is my onReceive Class in my BroadcastReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"In onReceive");
    if(intent.getAction().equals(INTENT_ACTION))
    {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,sendActivity.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);     
    }
}
```

Dialog Styled Actvity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWidgetDialogCancel"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Part of my Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.widget.sendActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this line if anyone else is interested

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```